# Couldn't call method UNetDomainReload because the class NetworkIdentity or method couldn't be found

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game using Unity 3D and Git with my team. It was working fine until I kinda messed up while merging (I think I gitignored the wrong files and they kinda conflicted with each other so I removed some of my meta files). Now, Unity is telling me in the console that:

> Couldn't call method UNetDomainReload because the class NetworkIdentity or method couldn't be found.

How can I resolve this problem? My game absolutely has nothing to do with network and multiplayer. If you need any information, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code where the error occurs, as well as the issue?

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't occur anywhere. Both the parents of the merging works fine, but the child after merging contains the aforementioned error. The error message is just there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to mitigate the problem with `Assets -> Reimport All`. Pretty sure this is not the best solution though...

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem because some of external components were built with different '.net' version. Try to change this setting: Menu -> Edit -> Project Settings -> Player, then find this field: Scripting Runtime Version and change it to another one.